# mp3blaster ( commandline interface player) not playing files

Tags: software-installation, mp3, tools

I installed `mp3blaster` using `apt-get` but it didn't work (*doesn't play specified files*).

After that failed attempt, I removed and purged the player.  I downloaded the player as a tarball. How do I install the application and launch it so that it works?.

**P.S** I have read the provided README and *tar.bz2* installation instructions.

Comment: @Zanna  installed with `apt-get` but didn't play, purged and downloaded the tarball

Comment: There is a solution to the audio output error: compile against libsdl1.2-dev, this gets around a cumbersome commandline to start mp3blaster...

Comment: @andrew.46 that is very useful... may I add to my answer? If you prefer not it's ok... I upvoted your magnificent one-liner :)

Comment: @Zanna Actually some unkindly soul has also downvoted my answer :(. Why don't you absorb as much of my answer as is useful (feel free to use the checkinstall syntax etc) and then I will delete my own answer. That way there will be one really solid answer in place.....

Comment: @andrew.46 that was indeed unkind, and strange :( I have edited, and my answer lacks the elegance of yours but I believe it is significantly more useful than it was before. Please comment if you think I should fix anything, and thank you for your generous assistance :)

Comment: @Zanna Your answer looks great :). I have not tested wget from sourceforge without the `--content-disposition` option, this is sometimes needed if you don't want an oddly named archive. I cannot look at the moment as I am at work and surrounded by windows :(. My own answer is deleted now...

Comment: @andrew.46 I tested it and it comes out clean :) thanks again

Comment: How did you launch it? I installed it with sudo apt-get install mp3blaster and ran it from the terminal with `mp3blaster file.mp3` Error free on 14.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note for <strike>the lazy</strike> others: you can install mp3blaster with

```
sudo apt-get install mp3blaster
```

For it to work properly, seemingly you need to launch it with

```
padsp mp3blaster
```

---

### **Here's how to compile it from source and eliminate the need for `padsp`:**

*Many* thanks to @andrew.46 for explaining that compiling against libsdl fixes this bug:

- [Launchpad: man page says audiodriver sdl works, but doesn't](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mp3blaster/+bug/752091))

Download the tarball:

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mp3blaster/mp3blaster-3.2.5.tar.gz
```

Extract it

```
tar xf mp3blaster*
```

Enter the directory

```
cd mp3blaster*
```

You need at least these dependencies to build it:

```
sudo apt-get install g++ libncurses5-dev  libsdl1.2-dev
```

Run

```
./configure --with-sdl
```

If there are errors, you need to install more packages. Please comment, and I will fix if possible. If *and only if* `configure` exits successfully you can run

```
make
```

then use `sudo make install` or better [use checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) to make it known to `dpkg` for easier removal (do `sudo apt-get install checkinstall` if you want to use it)

```
sudo checkinstall
```

follow the instructions...

Now you can launch && enjoy with

```
mp3blaster
```

[image]

Comment: launched correctly now...not playing mp3 files...exists with an error message

Comment: what's the message? Same as when you installed it with `apt-get`?

Comment: Launched the player correctly, when trying to open file , exists with message `Failed to open sound device`

Comment: @daumie try launching it with `padsp mp3blaster` [source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1617202) I can't test properly because I don't have audio drivers!

Comment: Now works , found a solution to the problem here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1617202 please update your answer accordingly

Comment: @daumie I found that too - see my previous comment. Edited

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the tarball for `mp3blaster` and according to `README`, to install `mp3blaster`, you do:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

PS: You should always read the README for installation instructions. The above commands are standard for installing software from a tarball too.

Comment: I read the README...installed but the player ain't working...did I miss a step/

Comment: Well then your question should have been explicit about the fact you did try to install; reading installation instructions is not the same as executing them. Did you see any error messages when you tried to install?

Comment: I'll update the question.No error messages thrown..just doesn't play...I have used the player before on another machine<<if that helps

Comment: You are probably missing dependencies, although `./configure` should have told you about that. See @Zanna's answer and see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, I was missing  `g++ libncurses5-dev`. now works, thanks